# Чтение элементов XML и их Под-Элементов

Tags: c#, winforms

Существет файл XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<specifications>

<s>Test1</s>
   <sg>014</sg>
   <sg>016</sg>
   <sg>014</sg>
   <sg>014</sg>
   <sg>016</sg>

<s>Test2</s>
   <sg>015</sg>
   <sg>017</sg>
   <sg>017</sg>
   <sg>017</sg>

</specifications>
```

И так же существует форма, на которой поставлено два ComboBox-а.

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы при выборе в Комбобоксе1 (Test1), в Комбобоксе2 отображалось только то, что принадлежит Test1 - (014, 016),  и соответсвенно при выборе в Комбобоксе1 (Test2), в Комбобоксе2 отображалось (015, 017). 
Чтобы в комбобоксе2 отображалось, все нужное и без повторений

Пытался что-то сделать таким образом

```
 XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("Specification.xml");
        XmlNodeList Listik = xDoc.SelectNodes("//s"); 
        foreach (XmlNode name in Listik)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(name.InnerText);
            XmlNodeList Listik1 = xDoc.SelectNodes("//sg");
            foreach (XmlNode name1 in Listik1)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(name1.InnerText);
                object[] mas = comboBox2.Items.OfType<string>().Distinct().ToArray();
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                comboBox2.Items.AddRange(mas);
            }


        }
```

Но честно говоря, до логического завершения так довести и не смог.

Что посоветуете?

И да, я знаю, что вопрос наверно 100% легкий. Отчаянно туплю...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

начнем с того, что неправильно построен xml файл, вот правильный вариант в твоем случае:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<specifications>

<s name="Test1">
   <sg>014</sg>
   <sg>016</sg>
   <sg>014</sg>
   <sg>014</sg>
   <sg>016</sg>
</s>
<s name="Test2">
   <sg>015</sg>
   <sg>017</sg>
   <sg>017</sg>
   <sg>017</sg>
</s>
</specifications>
```

далее, ты создаешь 2 ComboBox, первому добавляешь событие SelectedIndexChanged и в зависимости от этого меняешь значение во втором

```
public List<string> ListTest1 { get; } = new List<string>();

public List<string> ListTest2 { get; } = new List<string>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load("Specification.xml");

    XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

    foreach (XmlElement xnode in xRoot)
    {
        XmlNode attr = xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name");

        comboBox1.Items.Add(attr.Value);

        foreach (XmlNode childnode in xnode.ChildNodes)
        {
            switch (attr.Value)
            {
                case "Test1":
                        if(!ListTest1.Contains(childnode.InnerText))
                            ListTest1.Add(childnode.InnerText);
                        break;
                case "Test2":
                        if (!ListTest2.Contains(childnode.InnerText))
                            ListTest2.Add(childnode.InnerText);
                        break;
            }                        
        }
    }
}

private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;

    string selectedValue = (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem;

    switch (selectedValue)
    {
        case "Test1":
            comboBox2.DataSource = ListTest1;
            break;
        case "Test2":
            comboBox2.DataSource = ListTest2;
            break;
    }

}
```